# vaex ValueError: Could not find a class (AggSum_object), seems object is not supported

Tags: python, dask, vaex

I got the following error while doing aggregation

dfv = vaex.from_csv(_path + 'sample.csv')
_monetary = dfv.groupby('CusUnique',agg=vaex.agg.sum('Trn_AMT'))

which returns.

"ValueError: Could not find a class (AggSum_object), seems object is not supported"

Comment: when i tested with 24 mil number of records , then it works. But when i tested with my records total around 84 mil records, then the above value error return.

Comment: I am a bit confused by the code example.. there are some typos perhaps?
Also, once you use your full data, can you check that all of it is of numeric type? Maybe some string has snuck into that column or something, in which case the aggregation might not work.